# Value getting stored in a weird way in List<String>

Tags: apex, controller, list, sort

I have this below method which returns unique values of Name. And this is used in VF page in a multiselect picklist.

```
Set<String> uniqueCustomObjectSet = new Set<String>();           
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    for(Custom_Package__c sl:[Select s.Name From Custom_Package__c s])
    {
    uniqueCustomObjectSet.add(sl.Name);
    }
    List<String> uniqueCustomObjectList = new List<String>(uniqueCustomObjectSet);

    for(integer i=0; i<uniqueCustomObjectList.size(); i++){
    options.add(new SelectOption(uniqueCustomObjectList[i],uniqueCustomObjectList[i]));
    }


    return options;

    }
```

On every selection of Name from Multiselect picklist a method is called from Action:support which in turn calls a method. In this method I am trying to get the max value in the list and pass it on to the SOQL query.

```
public List<string> discountSchedule {
        get {
            if (discountSchedule == null) {
                discountSchedule = new List<string>();
            }
            return discountSchedule ;
        }
        set;
        }

    public void updateMarketOptions() {
            marketOptions.clear();
            marketOptions3.clear();
            marketOptionsadd.clear();
            integer len=discountSchedule.size()-1;
            String maxvalue = discountSchedule[len];
            for (Custom_Package__c cp1 : [select Id, Market__c, state__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c ,Space_Discount__c, Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c from Custom_Package__c where Name =:maxvalue order by Market__c]) {
            if(notfirst){
            if(marketOptions2.contains(cp1.Market__c)){
            marketOptions3.add(cp1.Market__c);
            }
            }else{
                 marketOptions2.add(cp1.Market__c);
                 marketOptions3.add(cp1.Market__c);
                }
                 cp=cp1;
            }
            marketOptionsadd.addAll(marketOptions3);
            for(String s: marketOptionsadd){
            marketoptions.add(new SelectOption(cp.Id,s));
            }
            notfirst = true;     
            }
```

When I pass the list like below in vf page -

[image]

I am getting issue as Market__c is not populating properly.. when i check in the debug log i found this -

[image]

The value is getting stored in an unordered way.

Comment: String maxvalue = discountSchedule[len]; this code will not return max value, check if issue with where condition.

Comment: Hi Prabhat.. Can u plz let me know how to return the max value in a List<String>.. If I am using test, test3, test12...... In debug log i am getting ...[EXTERNAL]|CustomPackageWrapper set(discountSchedule,[test, Test12, test3])...

Comment: len variable i am getting = 2, maxvalue = test3 but maxvalue should be Test12 as per the order...can u plz help in this...

Comment: Use discountSchedule.sort() before max value calculation.

Comment: after applying sort before maxvalue assiging..in vf page i used values like  test, test3, test12.... In the debug log i got...CustomPackageWrapper set(discountSchedule,[test, Test12, test3])...Dont know whts happening...

Comment: discountSchedule.size() = 3, len = 2, maxvalue = test3...

Comment: Test12 is returning as max values. Change this integer len=discountSchedule.size()-1; to integer len=discountSchedule.size();

Comment: I am getting System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1 error in  ...String maxvalue = discountSchedule[len];.... line...

Answer (score 3):

Sid - you have many ordering issues all interplaying with each other

1. Your SOQL query that places results in a set - by definition - has no order defined
2. Your assignment of the set to a List of selectOptions; hence, also no order defined
3. Chosen2 jQuery plugin that may or may not introduce a new sort order

So, once the update back to the controller happens, you have a multi-select picklist field in the controller `discountSchedule` that is represented by a list.  You can get the highest value in a collating sequence by simply using `discountSchedule = discountSchedule.sort()` and then picking off the last element. If the collating sequence isn't the right sort order, then put discountSchedule into an inner class that implements the Comparable interface, then when you call sort() on the list of someInnerClass, you can define your own sort order, [see examples in Apex Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) or elsewhere here in StackExchange

Comment: hi crop..for the....... 2. Your assignment of the set to a List of selectOptions; hence, also no order defined...........how to order this...

Answer (score -2):

use order by name on soql query.

Comment: order by name it will sort it according to the alphabet.. but here the issue is something else...here i need to get the max value present in List<String>..