# How To assign List<String> to map and pass the key to the SOQL parameter

Tags: apex

I have a List like below -

```
public List<string> discountSchedule {
        get {
            if (discountSchedule == null) {
                discountSchedule = new List<string>();
                discountSchedule.sort();
            }
            return discountSchedule ;
        }
        set;
 }
```

I need to assign this `discountSchedule` to a Map and pass the key to the below SOQL --

```
for (Custom_Package__c cp1 : [select Id, Market__c, state__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c ,Space_Discount__c, Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c from Custom_Package__c where Name =:discountSchedule order by Name]) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement I believe you want to use list of name for filter

You can use

```
for (Custom_Package__c cp1 : [select Id, Market__c, state__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c ,Space_Discount__c, Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c from Custom_Package__c where Name IN:discountSchedule order by Name]) {

}
```

No need to convert into map

If still  you want to convert

```
map<String, String> mapstr = new map<String, String>();
for (String str: discountSchedule)
{
mapstr.put(str, str);
}

for (Custom_Package__c cp1 : [select Id, Market__c, state__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c ,Space_Discount__c, Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c from Custom_Package__c where Name IN:mapstr.keyset() order by Name]) {

}
```

Comment: Hi Ratan.. Thanks for the ans...I was trying to resolve one issue which i have mentioned in of my post..can u also advice how to resolve this issue...http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99332/need-help-value-getting-stored-in-a-weird-way-in-liststring/99380#99380

Comment: @Sid - Putting it in a map will not solve your issues in any way. You are ordering by name so regardless of if it is a map or a list it will always be ordered by what is in your Order By clause.

Comment: But Eric...its not the issue at frontend.. if u check the post which i have mentioned above..at debug log its creating a different sequence....i am worried about tht..

Comment: Hi Eric/Ratan....In my above get;set .... I am passing Cooking, American at the vf page multiselect..when i see in the debug i see in set as American, Cooking...How is the Set method sorting the order...

Comment: @Sid pls update your above question with your requirement an try elaborate more so we can help you

Comment: @Sid - There is NO sorting in a set. By definition it is unordered....While the order is the same for every iteration (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213516&language=en_US) the initial iteration is unpredictable. Meaning the first iteration there is no way to guess the order but every subsequent iteration the order will be the same as the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly assign this list to Map. For this you need to write for loop.

```
for(string s: list)
     map.put(s.key, s.value);
```

but as your list is string so i don't know how you assign this to Map. If its a list of Id then there is a better approach.

Create a set and then use method `Set.Addall(list)` and then pass this SET in SOQL.